# SQL Server loop to run a script based off a date?

Tags: sql-server

Not sure where to start searching. Basically I have a script that returns multiple metrics from tables. It uses an as of date (each monday). I was able to collect the past years Mondays "As of dates" Now I want to be able to write a script that will use those dates instead of running it manually 52 times.

The end table looks like this:

```
 Office   | Metric_1| Metric_2|As_of_Date|
 12       | 2000000 |  1      |2017-06-28|
 15       | 4000000 |  2      |2017-06-28|
 20       | 8000000 |  4      |2017-06-28|
```

I;d greatly appreciate any direction or help.
Thank you

The end result table would look like this:

```
Office   | Metric_1| Metric_2|As_of_Date|
 12       | 2000000 |  1      |2017-06-28|
 15       | 4000000 |  2      |2017-06-28|
 20       | 8000000 |  4      |2017-06-28|
 12       | 2000000 |  1      |2017-05-15|
 15       | 4000000 |  2      |2017-05-15|
 20       | 8000000 |  4      |2017-05-15|
```

Comment: it is not clear, what you mean "as of dates" and the whole question overall, could you provide some more detailed info?

Comment: Where's your script? What is the intended script supposed to do, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get you wrong, what you need is to find all the data that has `as_of_date` being in this year, so all you need is to limit date only to this year, some of the examples on how to do it is below

```
select * from table where as_of_date >= to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and as_of_date <= to_date('2017-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

or the better way

```
select * from table where WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM as_of_date ) = 2017
```

**UPD:** as you stated in your comment, in order to get some data from **DataTable** according to the **DateTable** you mentioned you can use join like below:

```
SELECT A.* FROM DATATABLE A RIGHT JOIN DATETABLE B ON A.AS_OF_DATE = B.AS_OF_DATE
```

Comment: Yes, I have already compiled a list of the "as of dates" needed. Now I want to know how do I get them to run in the script and produce the separate sets of data I need. For example I would need say 10 "as of dates" that would be used to run the script 10 times.. does that make sense?

Comment: I used a date table to collect the dates I need in a temp table.. I want to use those to plugin to the script which would run off those dates.

Comment: @Swazzy I don't know how to do the temp table using standart SQL, but if you know the use of PL/SQL you can do it by using cursors, I only provide you the script so that you won't have to do it manually as your question mentioned